# case statement in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

So,
what i am trying to accomplish here is pretty straight forward, i have a column fare in my spreadsheet and i want to add anew column that would say if the fare is <10 ,10<20,20<30,30+

I came up with this solution but it seems like it is not using a shortcut condition, is there a case statement or any other method i can use to achieve what i want?

> =if(J19<10,"<10",IF(AND(J19>10,J19<20),"10<20",IF(AND(J19>20,J19<30),"20<30","30+"
>   )))

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1,-1)&"<"&ROUNDUP(A1,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the conditions in a nested set of `if` functions are evaluated consecutively, you do not need to repeat previous conditions using `and`. Also note that your original formula doesn't do the right thing at the borderlines, e.g. if J19=10.

So although Excel does not have a `case` function, the following is simpler and more accurate than your original:

```
=if(J19<10,"<10",IF(J19<20,"10<20",IF(J19<30,"20<30","30+")))
```

Comment: your formula doesn't work, when J19=7 the result is +30

Comment: Please check if J19 contains the number 7 or the text "7".

Comment: it does contain the number 7 and not the text "7"

Comment: There is something weird happening then. It is a straight-forward formula that works fine for me. Can you upload a copy of the spreadsheet somewhere I can take a look?

Comment: here it is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1udSgyJfy9M7gGgzDnRgC1NudDb7VQmiSk1R4XG15fs8/edit#gid=499778724

Comment: Sorry for the time delay. The problem is that your formula in that spreadsheet is off by one row. e.g. the formula in N2 is testing the value in J1, where it should be testing J2.